# Can't access Cell data in DataGridView VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, cell

I've got a project in Visual Studio 2017, using VB.NET that populates a DataGridView using a DataTable. The data appears fine in the grid, but when I try to access the cell value in the SelectionChanged event, I always get Nothing. Here's the event:

```
    Private Sub grdBooks_SelectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grdBooks.SelectionChanged
    If Not grdBooks.CurrentRow Is Nothing Then
        If grdBooks.CurrentRow.Index > -1 Then
            Dim X As String = grdBooks.Rows(0).Cells(0).Value
            Dim Y  = grdBooks(0, 0).Value
            UpdateEditPanel(False)
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

So both X and Y should give me the same value from the grid at position 0,0 but they don't. I've used this before in other projects. Does anybody have any ideas?

Thanks, Colin

Comment: Did you by chance add a `DataGridviewColumn` with (`Visible=False`) to the `DataGridview` prior to binding the `DataTable`?  Possibly via the designer.  Try adding `DataGridView1.Columns.Clear()` before setting the `DataSource`.

Comment: You have a confusing post.  You say the cell is always nothing, but then you say x and y should be the same value but aren't.  Which issue is it?  The code you posted does not support either issue.

Comment: The code sample you provided works for me. I see the value in cell 0/0 when I select different items in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused by this post aswell but I hope this helps you resolve the problem. Possible solution #1

```
Dim X As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString
```

or

```
Dim X As String = DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
```

If you are able to provide more code, I'm sure we can resolve this Issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to click the cell from the Grid, try this:

```
Private Sub grdBooks_CellContentClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles grdBooks.CellContentClick

    Dim selectedRow As DataGridViewRow

    selectedRow = grdBooks.Rows(e.RowIndex)

    Dim x as string = selectedRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()


End Sub
```